# How to use Model Data in Checkboxlist in OctoberCMS?

Tags: laravel, octobercms

I am working with OctoberCMS and I would like to use all entries of Model called Service in a Checkboxlist. Then the user should select a maximum number of 4 items.

How can I do that?

I can't find any solution where I should define the list of entries for the Checkboxlist.

Thanks for your help.

Regards

kay899

Answer (score 0):

You can define the options for the checkboxlist the same way you do for the dropdown. In your case its sounds like a good idea to use the model function to define the options like this:

```
public function getServicesOptions($value, $formData)
{
    $services = Service::all();

    # TODO: format the $services array as needed

    return $services;
}
```

PS. this should be in the model of the form, not the Service.

Comment: thx for fast answer. But I use this in Dynamic Syntax parser, so to say in my layout file. Where to put this then?

Comment: Are you using it in the backend or in the frontend?

Comment: only in backend, want to select the items which then should be rendered

Comment: Do you know which model is your form using?

Comment: RainLab Pages (Static Pages Plugin). Can I extend this somehow?

Comment: In that case take a look here: https://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/extending#extending-backend-form

I'm afraid I dont have time right now to give you a code example